# How can I change the date from the beginning of the month to the end of the month in a dateframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a following data frame:

```
index        0
2000-03-01  4.03333
2000-06-01  3.93333
2000-09-01  4.0
2000-12-01  3.9
2001-03-01  4.23333
2001-06-01  4.4
```

the index is pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex type. And I want to change the index from the beginning of the month to the end of the month, say, `2000-03-01` to `2000-03-31` for all the indices. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I tried to use datetime.replace() function to replace the day. But somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: consider providing the minimum amount of code for others to examine and troubleshoot the issue you're having...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually, I'm really new to Python, I just don't know how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tseries.offsets` and use [`MonthEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
In [143]:
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
df.index += MonthEnd()
df

Out[143]:
                  0
index              
2000-03-31  4.03333
2000-06-30  3.93333
2000-09-30  4.00000
2000-12-31  3.90000
2001-03-31  4.23333
2001-06-30  4.40000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how to shift the index to the end of each month. You can choose different frequency by changing the `freq` parameter (see [Offset Aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)).

```
# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': [4.0333300000000003,
  3.9333300000000002,
  4.0,
  3.8999999999999999,
  4.2333300000000005,
  4.4000000000000004]},
 index = pd.to_datetime(['2000-03-01',
  '2000-06-01',
  '2000-09-01',
  '2000-12-01',
  '2001-03-01',
  '2001-06-01']))

# Shifting
df.shift(periods=1, freq='M')

                  0
2000-03-31  4.03333
2000-06-30  3.93333
2000-09-30  4.00000
2000-12-31  3.90000
2001-03-31  4.23333
2001-06-30  4.40000
```

Comment: 2000-09-29, this is a problem it should be 2000-09-30

Comment: I've update my answer. It's correct now with the `M` frequency.